Protein quaternary structure in ViewLite
I want to represent the octameric structure of a metalloprotein in the ViwerLite program.  I loaded the PDB file related to the protein, but the progranul only displays a monomeric structure (a single metal ion also appears).  What could I do to visualize the octameric structure?

Suggestion: add a link to the program's source, state the version/release and release date you use, substantiate your observation by adding an illustration generated by the program. Else, how could one replicate your findings?

Quite possibly you simple got one unit in .pdb and need a file with eight.

Perhaps the program displays only the crystallographic motif.  If this happens to coincide with a special position, the space group's symmetry operators could "complete" the molecule (for instance a centre of inversion, a mirror plane, a proper rotation axis), e.g., crystallographic models in monoclinic $P2_1/c$,  orthorhombic $P2_12_12_1$ (as some of the more frequently seen ones for organic matter), or trigonal $R3c$. It then were useful to amend the question with structure code of the database, too.  Perhaps just a click away (e.g., Jmol).
